# There is an issue with my batch file code, can't find the problem

Tags: batch-file

So I'm making a very ambitious game using batch to challenge myself. I've been working on the "shop" segment of this game but for some reason when I enter 'b' or 'B' it doesn't send me back to the menu, but reads it as I wanted to buy a medkit and sends me to the "medkit purchased" line of code. I've tried to add `pause >nul` and `pause` between the shop line of code and the purchased line of code, but it didn't help. I also tried double checking to see if I typed menu right many times. There has to be something I'm missing, help appreciated, I've been messing with it for almost 2 hours now.

Edit: I have not entered the other events yet, only medkit and go back to menu.
Edit2: I've added some more variables and instead of taking me to them it takes me to the medkit code again.
Edit: I removed the percents, you guys can stop bugging me bout it. The issue still is not fixed and I do not have choice.exe so choice commands don't work.

Here is the code:

```
:shop
cls
echo Welcome to the shop!
echo Money: $%money%
echo.
echo 1. Buy Med Kit -$30
echo 2. Buy Shotgun Ammo (1) -$15
echo 3. Buy Assult Rifle Ammo (5) -$20
echo 4. Buy Missle (1) -$50
echo 5. View Armor
echo 6. View Modifiers
echo.
echo Enter 'B' to go back.
echo.
set /p %shopOp%=
if '%shopOp%' == '1' goto medkit1
if '%shopOp%' == '2' goto sg1
if '%shopOp%' == '3' goto ar1
if '%shopOp%' == '4' goto rpg1
if '%shopOp%' == '5' goto armors1
if '%shopOp%' == '6' goto mods1
if '%shopOp%' == 'B' goto menu
if '%shopOp%' == 'b' goto menu

:medkit1
cls
set /a money=%money%-30
if %money% LSS 0 goto noBuy1
set /a medK=%medK%+1
echo You bought 1 medkit for $30!
echo You now have %medK% med kits now!
echo.
echo Press enter to continue
pause >nul
goto shop

:noBuy1
cls
set /a money=%money%+30
echo You dont have enough money!
echo You have $%money%. You need $30.
echo.
echo Press enter to continue
pause >nul
goto shop
```

Comment: You don't use percent symbols when assigning a value to a variable. `set /p %shopOp%=`.  Remove the percent symbols.

Comment: Follow @Squashman's note. Try unconditional `goto menu` instead of `if  /I '%shopOp%' == 'b' goto menu` (what-if somebody inputs e.g. "C"?) BTW, I'd use [`choice` command](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) for a one-letter input…

Comment: Thanks @Squashman but that did not fix the code. It is definitely useful though, I didn't know the percents were unnecessary.

Comment: @JosefZ thanks, but then how will you be able to select what item you'd like to buy. Also I'll take a look ate choice commands.

Comment: Also `set /a money=%money%-30`, should read `set /a money=money-30` or better `set /a money-=30`; `set /a medK=%medK%+1`, should read `set /a medK=medK+1` or better `set /a medK+=1`; and yes, `set /a money=%money%+30` should read `set /a money=money+30` or better `set /a money+=30`.

Comment: If "*it takes me to the medkit code again*", means you are probably falling through the `if '%shopOp%' ==` comparisons. Single quotes are not special, so use double quotes to surround values.

Comment: Supposedly `CHOICE /C 123456b /M "Money: $%money%"` and then tests _errorlevel_ (in descending order) as `if ERRORLEVEL 7 goto menu` then `if ERRORLEVEL 6 goto mods1` then `if ERRORLEVEL 5 goto armors1` and so on

Comment: @Squashman I'm not to bright, I misread your comment, I see that I added percents while defining the variable. Thanks for the help. Code fixed

Comment: `echo 2. Buy Shotgun Ammo (1) -$15`, escape echoed closing parentheses i.e. `)` with `^)` to make the character literal.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61823099/12343998) That utitlises Subroutnes to build menu / option screens and structures Choice to navigate to the available option labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so you don't have choice. How about xcopy?
A version adapted from the link in my comment that substitutes the choice utility with xcopy to return keypress:

```
@Echo off
    Set Echo.ID=Call :ID.Label "%%~1" "%%~2"
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    Title Menu Navigation Example
:Bar
    Set "Left.Date="
    IF /I "!Left.Bar!" == "Yes" Goto :Date
    Call :[+Menu] "Bar" "Drink Fight Chat Leave"
Goto :Bar
:Date
    Set "Left.Bar="
    IF /I "!Left.Date!" == "Yes" Goto :Bar
    Call :[+Menu] "Date" "Dinner Flirt Leave"
Goto :Date

:[+Menu] <Location / Core Menu option> <Sub Actions / Menu Items as list>
::: - Build menu and choice list for display
    CLS
    Set "CHOICES="
    Set "Actions="
    For %%A in (%~2) Do (
        Set "Option=%%~A"
        Set Actions=!Actions! "%%~A"
        Set CHOICES=!CHOICES! "!Option:~0,1!"
        Set "Option=[!Option:~0,1!]!Option:~1,100!"
        Echo !Option!
    )
::: - Return key literal from xcopy command and call relevent menu item with Identifying Params
    Set "Option="
    Set Key=
    For /F "Delims=" %%A in ('xcopy /w "%~f0" "%~f0" 2^>nul') do (
        If Not Defined Key Set "Key=%%A"
    )
    Set "Key=!Key:~-1!"
::: - Restrict keypress to available options, fall through to 'Goto :[Menu]' when no Call is made (Invalid keypress)
    For %%O in (%~2) Do (
        Set "Option=%%~O"
        Set "Option=!Option:~0,1!"
        If /I "!Option!" == "!Key!" Call :[%~1_%%~O-!Key!] "%%~1 %%~O" "%~1"
    )
Goto :[+Menu]

:[Bar_Drink-D]
    %Echo.ID%
Goto :!Loc!
:[Bar_Fight-F]
    %Echo.ID%
Goto :!Loc!
:[Bar_Chat-C]
    %Echo.ID%
Goto :!Loc!
:[Bar_Leave-L]
    %Echo.ID%
    Set "Left.Bar=Yes"
Goto :!Loc!

:[Date_Dinner-D]
    %Echo.ID%
Goto :!Loc!
:[Date_Flirt-F]
    %Echo.ID%
Goto :!Loc!
:[Date_Leave-L]
    Set "Left.Date=Yes"
    %Echo.ID%
Goto :!Loc!

:ID.Label <%~1> <%~2>
    Title %~1
::: - Identify return Label
    Set "Loc=%~2"
Exit /B
```